# How to update weight vector which is include a class variable or attribute. i cannot update my class weight vector by gradient descent

Tags: python, class, oop, attributes

```
class PytorchLinearRegression():


    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=torch.tensor(np.array(x),dtype=torch.float32)
        self.y=torch.tensor(np.array(y),dtype=torch.float32)
        self.w=torch.normal(2,3,size=(self.x.shape[1],1),requires_grad=True)
        self.b=torch.zeros([1],requires_grad=True)
        self.m=self.x.shape[0] 


    def prediction(self):
        return torch.add(torch.mm(self.w,x),self.b)    

    def CostFunction(self):

        return torch.sqrt(torch.square(torch.subtract(y,torch.add(torch.mm(self.w,x),self.b)))/self.m)

    def Iteration(self,learning_rate=1e-5,epoch):
        
        for epoch in range(epoch):
            cost=LinearRegression.CostFunction(self)
            cost.backward()
            with torch.no_grad():
              w-=w.grad*1e-5
              b-=b.grad*1e-5
              w.grad.zero_()
              b.grad.zero_()
```

I want to create a LinearRegression class where used pytorch. but the main problem is model parameter doesn't update when called iteration method.